# Face Detection with less cpu load cv2

Tags: python, computer-vision, cpu-usage, face-detection, opencv

for a university project I am programming a face mask recognition. For detecting faces, I use the cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_detector.xml'). As I noticed, this program is taking up way too much of the CPU resulting in a heavily disordered video stream frame rate.
I am running the code on a MacBook Air with a 1.6Hz Dual Core (Intel Core i5).
Can someone explain what I can change to make it smoother? Or maybe recommend another face detection?
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
from matplotlib.pyplot import gray

# Disable tensorflow compilation warnings
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face_detector.xml')

# To capture video from webcam.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# To use a video file as input
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.mp4')

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('checkpoint19.ckpt')

i = 0
while True:
    # Read the frame
    _, img = cap.read()

    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 4)

    # save each frame as image with PNG format
    image = cv2.imwrite('database/{index}.png'.format(index=i), img)
    i += 1

    # cut out the fragment in the box of the image
    # Draw the rectangle around each face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        crop_img = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        resizedImg = cv2.resize(crop_img, (224, 224))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(resizedImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        imgArrNew = gray.reshape(1, 224, 224, 1)
        prediction = model.predict(imgArrNew)
        print(prediction)
        label = np.argmax(prediction)
        print(label)

        # font
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        # org
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            org = (x, y+h+30)

        # fontScale
        fontScale = 1
        # Blue color in BGR
        color = (255, 0, 0)
        # Line thickness of 2 px
        thickness = 2
        # output the predicted label/sign on the live-stream frame
        if label == 0:
            color = (0,0,225)
            label_out = "Mask off"
        if label == 1:
            color = (50,205,50)
            label_out = "Mask on"
        if label == 2:
            color = (0,255,225)
            label_out = "incorrect Mask"
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
        image1 = cv2.putText(img, label_out, org, font,
                             fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
    # Display
    cv2.imshow('Face_Regonition', img)
    # Stop if escape key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

haar cascaded classifier is slow. . To do detection in every single frame is hard for low-end computing devices.

The easiest way is to use a lower resolution image or lower FPS. But it will appear to be cheap

The better way is to use a detection and tracking framework where detection happens at a 1hz interval at a new thread and tracking can happen at 30hz, which human eye cant tell the difference.

For detection of face, you can choose any method such as hear, HOG, CNN and put it in a new thread.  In the main tracking thread (which can run in real time) update the model and predict the bounding box and display it.

You may look for the tracking from here. I suggest KCF based method for it is fast and reliable.

[image]

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/

Just put the detection box rect as input rect box for the tracking. THen it should work directly.

Comment: On the website it says: 
Use KCF when you need faster FPS throughput but can handle slightly lower object tracking accuracy
I did have some problems with the haar cascaded classifier, that it wasn't always able to detect the face properly. Instead it was rather detecting a scaffolding as a face instead of my face...
but i will try it anyway. Thank you for your fast answer, I will let you know if it works